# word 2007 set focus to text box

Tags: microsoft-word-2007, focus

I have a letterhead which has two "panes". The top pane is the header and has a lower rounded rectangle surrounding the text. Below that I want a similar pane with rounded corners into which I am able to type the contents of the letter. How do I draw the lower pane with a rounded corner rectangle as a border and set it so that when it opens the focus is within the pane and will not type over the edges and at the lower end of the pane it must switch to the same pane on page two?

Comment: Can you add a screenshot of what you have now?

Comment: sorry Karan - I dont know how to do that??

Comment: Press PrintScreen key, paste in Paint, save as JPG/PNG, upload to imgur.com, copy/paste links in comment or edit your question.